# Image loses clarity when it is put over a black background

Tags: images, black, white

The original image I do have is the one on the top of this screenshot, I would like it to have a black background. The problem as you can see below is the loss of clarity whenever it has a dark background.

[image]

Long story: I need that image to appear as a tile of a menu in a website (http://www.sharpmix.com/) that has a white background. I guess this is the way to go but I'm not a graphics designer at all, any ideas are welcome.

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone, I've ended up with this:

[image]

Comment: Zoom in on your black image... there's matting on it which makes the edge pixels darker.

Comment: Ok I thing I am understanding what you're pointing out, going to see if I can change that at the source. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you used the magic wand tool to select the white background with tolerance set at 32 and anti-aliasing on. If I do that, I get the same result.

Instead, set the tolerance to 1 and turn off anti-alias:

[image: Magic wand settings]

Here's a comparison of the difference:

[image: before and after comparison]

Zoomed in for better detail:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's normal. When you make the background dark gray, you decrease the contrast of your image. Maybe you should INVERT it:

[image]

Inverting it changes the colors. Playing with blending modes you can get this:

[image]

It really depends on what effect you are looking for.

Comment: I'm just looking for an 'ok' thing, it does not have to be perfect. Thank you, I am going to try what you've suggested and come back here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the contrast. If I had to guess, I would say this is the result of anti-aliasing from a magic wand selection